# Rabbeting concrete

Tags: concrete, routers

I am estimating an approach in which I'd make a [rabbet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbet) on a soft concrete wall. The dimension of the rabbet are roughly ~2cm x 3cm x 400cm.

My initial idea is to find a router bit (wood router) for concrete and use that.
Conceptually this sounds fairly simple, but have found close to none results when searching.

Is rabbeting concrete a plausible approach and if not what are the difficulties?

Comment: problem: unlike wood, there are no tools that cut concrete,  concrete saws use abrasive discs that wear away the concrete.  to approach the task with a router like tool would wear out lots of diamonds and make huge amounts of dust.

Comment: This sounds more than a bit like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the purpose of the rabbet (i.e. what is the real problem you're trying to resolve), and what is a "soft concrete" wall? Is that concrete that's starting to crumble from age?

Comment: Also, there's a third dimension to your cut. 3cm? 30m? Please revise to describe the project better.

Answer (score 1):

Use a masonry saw much like a chain saw but with a large disk instead of the bar.

Then make 2 cuts 1 horizontal and one vertical.

You will need to use a rail or guide to cut straight lines.

Comment: Is there something essentially different between a masonry saw and a woodworking circular saw with a diamond blade?

Comment: The power comes to mind.

Comment: this tool is know here as a "quick-cut saw" that may be a brand name.  water is used as a lubricant which prolongs the blade life,

Comment: Yes, a typical circular saw will have a tough time providing enough torque to keep the blade moving in poured concrete. Also, the concrete dust will destroy the bearings in short order.

Answer (score 0):

Use the a wall chaser, this is a tool electricians and plumbers use to cut chases (small trenches) in concrete, but fit only one blade (use a washer in place of the other(s)) do one cut from the top and one from the side.

[image]

Comment: What tool would that be, and why would it have more than one blade? This answer is confusing and incomplete.

Comment: It's a wall chaser, very common in Germany for example where pretty much all walls are full masonry. See my answer here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/185938/65622 It has 2 blades to make 2 parallel cuts at once in order to make a chase or slot in the wall.

Comment: Sexy tool.  I do not need one, but i **want** one. I could see that having it when you need it would be very useful.

Comment: you can probably rent one

Comment: It's like a hand-held dado stack for concrete. What's not to love!